# Chef convergence fails with ERROR: Unable to determine node name: configure node_name or configure the system's hostname and fqdn

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

My server fails to converge with the following messages. I am unable to figure where this error is coming from.

I am copying and pasting the chef stacktrace AFTER the client.log messages below:

Weird thing is that the client.rb file stacktrace is refering to does not even exist on this box.

Any help will be appreciated!

```
[root@xyz chef]# tail client.log

* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 

[2016-04-21T11:47:24-06:00] INFO: *** Chef 11.12.8 ***
[2016-04-21T11:47:24-06:00] INFO: Chef-client pid: 7309
[2016-04-21T11:47:24-06:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
[2016-04-21T11:47:24-06:00] ERROR: Unable to determine node name: configure node_name or configure the system's hostname and fqdn
[2016-04-21T11:47:24-06:00] ERROR: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
[2016-04-21T11:47:24-06:00] ERROR: Sleeping for 3600 seconds before trying again
[2016-04-21T11:51:10-06:00] INFO: SIGTERM received, exiting gracefully
```

---

STACK TRACE:

```
cat /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
Generated at 2016-04-21 11:47:24 -0600
Chef::Exceptions::CannotDetermineNodeName: Unable to determine node name:    configure node_name or configure the system's hostname and fqdn
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-  11.12.8/lib/chef/client.rb:299:in `node_name'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.8/lib/chef/client.rb:313:in `register'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.8/lib/chef/client.rb:416:in `do_run'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.8/lib/chef/client.rb:213:in `block in run'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.8/lib/chef/client.rb:207:in `fork'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.8/lib/chef/client.rb:207:in `run'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.8/lib/chef/application.rb:217:in `run_chef_client'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.8/lib/chef/application/client.rb:328:in `block in run_application'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.8/lib/chef/application/client.rb:317:in `loop'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.8/lib/chef/application/client.rb:317:in `run_application'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.8/lib/chef/application.rb:67:in `run'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.8/bin/chef-client:26:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/bin/chef-client:23:in `load'
/usr/bin/chef-client:23:in `<main>'[root@xyz chef]#
```

Comment: You are using a very old chef version btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure a `node_name` in your `/etc/chef/client.rb`.  Sometimes Ohai can figure this out on its own, but it doesn't seem like it in your case.  check `hostname`, `hostname -f`, and the `/etc/hostname` file to see what your servers are configured for.

I personally always define my `node_name` in chef, and then use the node name to set the hostname and fqdn... not the other way around as the Chef doc's recommend,  depends on your setup.

For example, my `client.rb` looks like:

```
chef_server_url "..."
client_fork true
log_location "/var/log/chef/client.log"
validation_client_name "...-validator"
verify_api_cert true # you might not want this one unless you have a valid cert
node_name "my_node_name" # Add this line
...
```

From the chef `client.rb` [docs](https://docs.chef.io/config_rb_client.html#settings)

> **node_name**
>   The name of the node. Determines which configuration should be applied and sets the client_name, which is the name used when authenticating to a Chef server. The default value is the FQDN of the chef-client, as detected by Ohai. In general, Chef recommends that you leave this setting blank and let Ohai assign the FQDN of the node as the node_name during each chef-client run.

Comment: will try this today and let you know. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively to the above, fix your server so that `hostname -f` shows something.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: In my case, `/usr/bin/hostname` was not installed on the VM image I'm using. Installing the hostname OS package resolves the Chef node_name problem.

Answer (score 1):

As you noticed, the configuration file does not exist. You have to create it and define the mentioned options. See the [documentation](https://docs.chef.io/config_rb_client.html) for details.

Answer (score 1):

As someone else pointed out 11.12.8 is kind of ancient code at this point.  You do seem to have the patch that was added to add `ohai[:machinename]` to the detection of the node_name which means that it should fall back to `hostname` (which should at least be the empty string I would think?  can we set an empty string for the hostname?) which would then avoid the exception.

Maybe your ohai version is also too old to have `node[:machinename]`?  But the patch to ohai and chef-client went in at basically the same time.

I literally was the last person to touch the node_name detection code and I can't see how you would be hitting that exception...

Best I can suggest is to see if you can replicate it on a more recent version of the omnibus install of chef-client because that "should" never happen.  Probably in order to debug this we need to know what the output of ohai is on your machine (including `hostname`, `machinename`, `fqdn` and `domain` values in particular).  Also the output of running `/bin/hostname` and `/bin/hostname -f`.

Comment: Thank you for your help.